# Incircle and Tangency Proof

Tags: geometry

Let the incircle of triangle $ABC$ be tangent to sides $\overline{BC}$, $\overline{AC}$, and $\overline{AB}$ at $D$, $E$, and $F$, respectively. Prove that triangle $DEF$ is acute.
[image: Diagram]

---

I can't prove that the triangles are similar, and we are not given any specific angle of side measurements.  I'm stuck, any answer is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hint: calculate angle $\widehat{EDF}$ for example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$CDE$ is an isosceles triangle, hence $\widehat{EDC}=\frac{\pi-C}{2}$. In a similar way, $\widehat{DBF}=\frac{\pi-B}{2}$, hence:
$$ \widehat{FDE}=\pi-\frac{\pi-B}{2}-\frac{\pi-C}{2}=\frac{B+C}{2}$$
and since $B+C<\pi$, $\widehat{FDE}$ is an acute angle. The same applies to $\widehat{FED}$ and $\widehat{DFE}$.

Comment: What do you mean by $B+C<\pi$?

Comment: @YunaKun: that the amplitude of the $B$ angle, plus the amplitude of the $C$ angle, is less than $180^\circ$ because $ABC$ is a triangle.

Comment: I haven't learned trig, so could you revise your solution so that it doesn't include advanced geometry?  Thanks!

Comment: Advanced geometry?! I am just considering the amplitude of some angles. I am unable to produce anything easier than this.

Comment: Is there a solution that doesn't include trig and/or amplitudes?  I haven't learned it yet is all that I'm saying.

Comment: You may compute the squared lengths of the sides of $DEF$ and apply the converse Pythagorean theorem, if you are happy with that, instead of using that the sum of the angles of a triangle is $180^\circ$.